# update pandas dataframe with adding new rows - how?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Let we have two Python pandas dataframes

df1:

```
key1 key2 volume1 volume2
111  bbb  fff      ggg
222  bbb  hhh      hhh
333  aaa  fff      hhh
```

df2:

```
key1 key2 volume1 volume2
222  bbb  hhh      HHH
333  aaa  fff      GGG
444  ccc  ggg      hhh
```

How to obtain a dataframe

df:

```
key1 key2 volume1 volume2
111  bbb  fff      ggg
222  bbb  hhh      HHH
333  aaa  fff      GGG
444  ccc  ggg      hhh
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to `outer` merge the dataframes `df1` and `df2` on columns `key1, key2`, then use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to update the values in column `volume1` and `volume2`:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['key1', 'key2'], how='outer', suffixes=['', '_r'])
df3['volume1'] = df3.pop('volume1_r').fillna(df3['volume1'])
df3['volume2'] = df3.pop('volume2_r').fillna(df3['volume2'])
```

Result:

```
# print(df3)

   key1 key2 volume1 volume2
0   111  bbb     fff     ggg
1   222  bbb     hhh     HHH
2   333  aaa     fff     GGG
3   444  ccc     ggg     hhh
```

Comment: @NikolayKazimirov Does this answer your question?